# Running watch task infinite loop on every grunt serve

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I keep getting this error:

[image]

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling `grunt-cli` with no results.

I've never had this happen before, but suddenly got the errors on every generated project with `yeoman` generators.

How can I fix this?

Just in case, here's the (undedited) `gruntfile.js`

https://gist.github.com/jsantana90/3dddeefbf28dfc8c1d42

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is old post, but for any new readers. Problem is that you reached the limit of the  system that has for how many files can be watched by a user.

So solution is to increase number of allowed watcher, that you can do with next command line:

```
$echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```